# Excel VBA To Filter by Column and Column Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code and it keeps giving the error "named argument not found" when trying to do the below.

Desired Behavior: For all sheets in active workbook cycle through and do the following; center align, auto fit rows, auto fit columns, then sort column named "assigned to" by value "Jack" then filter by "date" and oldest to newest.
Specific Problem: errors out whenever I get to the sort part

If able: I would also like to remove duplicates based on a column name not just the part below how I'm doing it below, would that be as easy as changing "36" to be the name "ID" ?

```
    Sub Filter_NOW()
    '
    ' Filter Macro
    '
    ' Declaration
      Dim wkSt As String
      Dim wkBk As Worksheet
      Dim temp As Variant
      Dim lastCol As Long
      Dim FilterCol As Variant
      Dim FilterColB As Variant

      wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name
' This Loops Through All Sheets
      For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          wkBk.Activate
          lastCol = wkBk.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          FilterCol = wkBk.Rows(1).Find("Assigned to")
          FilterColB = wkBk.Rows(1).Find("Date")

'This is to center align all rows
          wkBk.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
' Resize Columns
          wkBk.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
' Resize Rows
          wkBk.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
' Filter by Column Name and Value
          wkBk.Range("$A:$BB").AutoFilter Field:=FilterCol, Criteria1:="JACK"
' Filter by Column Name and Value
          wkBk.Range("$A:$BB").AutoFilter Field:=FilterColB, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
' Remove Duplicates
     wkBk.Range("$A$1:$AM$373").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=36, Header:= _
        xlYes
      Next wkBk
      Sheets(wkSt).Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: You could make it easy and tell us which line!?

Comment: You might want to change `lastCol = wkBk.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to `lastCol = wkBk.Cells(1, wkBk.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` and `Sheets(wkSt).Select` should be `Sheets(wkSt).Activate` (as you have correctly written before).

Comment: @SJR it highlights SortOn:= when it gives the error
- Ralph I tried that and still received the error. 
ty both for the suggestions and help

Comment: SortOn (and Order) are not parameters of Autofilter.

Comment: ahh ok, is there another way to do the sorting and order by biggest to smallest that is an autofilter param?

Comment: Actually not sure I am right, it may be valid in xl 2013 (?) In any case, I would do the Filter and then the Sort as two separate operations.

Comment: I mean, that is what I got from using "record macro" I just wanted to make it more generalized.